# Pyspark adding few seconds to time

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark

I am trying to add few seconds to time but I haven't been successful. Here is my example

```
import datetime
str1 = sc.parallelize(["170745","140840"])
aa = str1.map(lambda l: datetime.datetime.strptime(l, '%H%M%S').strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

yields

```
['17:07:45', '14:08:40']
```

but I want is

```
['17:07:52', '14:08:47']
```

How could I add 7 seconds to each converted time. I know `timedelta` is there but not sure about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `datetime.timedelta(0,7)` after you have convert your string to dates:

```
import datetime
str1 = sc.parallelize(["170745","140840"])
aa = str1.map(lambda l: (datetime.datetime.strptime(l, '%H%M%S') + datetime.timedelta(0,7)).strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

`aa.collect()` returns:

```
['17:07:52', '14:08:47']
```

Replacing the lambda with a regular function, arguably makes it easier to understand:

```
import datetime

def processdate(timeString):
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(timeString, '%H%M%S')
    date += datetime.timedelta(0,7)
    return date.strftime('%H:%M:%S')    

str1 = sc.parallelize(["170745","140840"])    
aa = str1.map(processdate)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use "+datetime.timedelta(seconds=7)" to solve this problem.

```
(datetime.datetime.strptime(l, '%H%M%S') + datetime.timedelta(seconds=7)).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

If you want to calculates the number of seconds between two times, minus two datetime.datetime object directly.

```
import datetime
starttime = datetime.datetime.now()
endtime = datetime.datetime.now()
print (endtime - starttime).seconds
```